# Simple image display using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried the below code to display an image using javascript but the image does not show. How do I do this using javascript? Thank you in advance.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/centem/pen/jwWBWd

HTML

```
<div>
        <img alt="dragon image" >
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var img = document.querySelect('img');
img.src = 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/4c/d0/a5/4cd0a541c00111cb84d736c0ceb04005.jpg';
```

Comment: It's [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), not `querySelect`. Have you checked the [console](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/2288/console#t=201706090827159624666&a=remarks-opening-the-console-0) for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `querySelect` should be `querySelector`.

For debugging, open the browser developer tools (F12) and look at the console. There will an error relating to your typo.

> Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelect is not a function

Comment: Well, I think question like that and answer for it should be a comment. Just my opinion.

Comment: Answers are for answers, comments are for comments. This answers the question. If you don't like the question, you are free to vote to close or comment on the question.

Comment: Wow! What an oversight. Thank you MrCode. Please accept my apologies for such a noob question.